# How can I convert this pandas dataframe to a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My sample function that returns a pandas data frame.

```py
def myFunction(data, row, col):

    return pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "helloWorld": [data["helloWorld"][row][col]],
        }
    )
```

How can I convert this pandas dataframe to a list?

**Docs & References:**

https://datatofish.com/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-list/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-pandas-dataframe-into-a-list/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.values.tolist()`

```python3
def myFunction(data, row, col):

    return pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "helloWorld": [data["helloWorld"][row][col]],
        }
    ).values.tolist()
```